# What is note-level warning in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Okay, I understand what are errors and warnings in the context of MySQL. But what's the need of note-level warning? I have already searched the MySQL documentation but didn't find anything relevant. It would be better if someone could shed some light on the what are they and why they are useful.

```
mysql> create database if not exists city;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings
    -> ;
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                        |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1007 | Can't create database 'city'; database exists |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please post an example of the query and the "note-level warning" output.

Comment: @bishop, I was initially expecting this would generate a warning, but this is certainly not the case.

Comment: Also, I can't find anything in the MySQL documentation where they explain what "notes" are? If you know the link pls share.

Comment: What is your question again. From what I understand from the docs, a note is just a warning that may or may not increment the warning count.

Comment: My question is apart from errors and warnings, what are notes? So does it mean the note and warning are same?

Comment: From what I understand from the docs: a note is just a warning that may or may not increment the warning count. A note is like a notice or informational message and user is able to configure if note warnings are counted as warnings or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always considered Note to be like an "FYI": something happened, or didn't, that may be of interest. The closest definition I can find in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_notes) is:

> ... events that do not affect the integrity of the reload operation

which is from the `sql_notes` server variable, one perhaps not often used outside of `mysqldump`.

---

Trawling through the [MySQL source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/search?q=SL_NOTE&unscoped_q=SL_NOTE), looks like `Sql_Condition::SL_NOTE` annotates warnings of this level. There are a few, but they are mostly as you'd expect for non-impactful information:

- Event already exists
- Table already exists
- `Query '%s' rewritten to '%s' by a query rewrite plugin`
- Password set

Sadly, I would have expected the code docblock to give a *little* more information about them, but it doesn't:

```
class Sql_condition {
 public:
  /**
    Enumeration value describing the severity of the condition.
  */
  enum enum_severity_level { SL_NOTE, SL_WARNING, SL_ERROR, SEVERITY_END };
```

This might warrant a documentation bug report to MySQL team.

---

Interestingly, [MariaDB has this to say](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/show-warnings/):

> A note is different to a warning in that it only appears if the sql_notes variable is set to 1 (the default), and is not converted to an error if strict mode is enabled.

My takeaway from that, in Maria and possibly by extension MySQL: notes *are* warnings, but ones that can be ignored because no data-loss or side-effect is described.